# nginx return 405 Not Allowed while using try_files and proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to use nginx to serve some static files and reverse proxy the restful api to the backend.
I use docker to wrap all of them.

The following is my config file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    # gzip config
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1k;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/javascript application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html @backend;
        error_page 405 @backend;
    }

    location /terminal {
        proxy_pass http://dns-management-backend:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    }

    location @backend {
        proxy_pass http://dns-management-backend:8080;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

The static files are served ok, but the restful api return me with `405 Not Allowed`.

Here are the logs of nginx

```
192.168.16.2 - - [19/Sep/2019:02:59:38 +0000] "POST /sys/login HTTP/1.1" 405 796 "http://dns-management.api.my.domain/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.75 Safari/537.36" "113.55.15.1"
```

Comment: If you would like to change the error code from 405, try: `error_page 405 = @backend;`

Comment: @RichardSmith, Thanks for your advice. However I find the root cause, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I find the cause, it was the wrong use of `try_files` directive, If the request url is `POST /sys/login`, then `POST /index.html` is served. So the 405 Not Allowed occured.

The fix is simple, change `try_files` directive to `try_files $uri $uri/index.html @backend;`